# Azure devops allow IP's rules of Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine

I have a VM on Azure that runs SQL Server and I want to update my databases in a build pipeline of Azure devops. But the port of SQL Server is allowed to just some IP's and I don't want to expose for everyone... It is possible to update the allowed IP's in the build?

I found this link that could help to get the IP's of the hosted : https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-ip-range

Microsoft update every week a json with the pipeline host IP''s but in the json are the services and the ips, but I don't know which the name of the service that I should get the IP's. I didn't find anything like "devops" or "pipeline".

Besides that, would be possible to auto update the allowed ip's in the build pipeline? I found this post: https://blog.simontimms.com/2020/01/10/2020-01-10-Allow-hosted-agents-through-firewall/ but I don't know how to edit my pipeline to do that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm the ip adress of the Microsoft-hosted agent in Json file, you need to check the region of the Organizaiton.

You could navigate to `Organization Settings -> Overview` and check the region of the organization.

Then you could search the `AzureCloud.<region>` in Json file to get the Ipaddress Prefixes.

[image]

To run the Blog's script, you could add the `Azure Powershell` task in the pipeline.

[image]

By the way, you need to create a Azure Service connection before using this task.

In addition you may encounter this issue.

> ##[error]No MSFT_NetFirewallRule objects found with property 'DisplayName' equal to ' Remote Event Monitor'.  Verify the value of
> the property and retry.

The cause of this issue is that a firewall rule with this name that does not exist.

You need to use [New-NetFirewallRule script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps) to create a new firewall with the target name.

For example:

`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Test" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 80 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow`

Then you could set the firewall rule with the Set-NetFirewallRule script.

Comment: Hi Kevin, 
Thank you very much for your answer. I will try to do it, but I think that will work because now I can understand what I need to do :D

Answer (score 0):

I’m on my phone so I can’t test this, but you can probably find the Public IP of the hosted agent you are on in a task using a command like ‘ nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com’ and then add it to your NSG and then remove it when you are done.

Tested from cloud shell in the Azure app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNDi3.jpg